# Cannot instantiate the type

Tags: java

I am new to Java, I have below code, and getting exception like

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot instantiate the type Calculator2Service
    The method getCalculator2Port() is undefined for the type Calculator2Service

    at com.theopentutorials.ws.calc2.client.Calc2Client.main(Calc2Client.java:13)
```

Please some one help..

---

```
package com.theopentutorials.ws.calc2.client;

import com.theopentutorials.ws.calc2.*; 

public class Calc2Client {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;         
        int b = 12;         
        Calculator2Service calcService = new Calculator2Service();         
        Calculator2 calc = calcService.getCalculator2Port();         
        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + calc.add(a, b));         
        System.out.println(a + " - " + b + " = " + calc.sub(a, b)); 

    }

}
```

Comment: Please have a look at `The method getCalculator2Port() is undefined for the type Calculator2Service`.

Comment: Answer lies in `Calculator2Service` class

Answer (score 0):

You should define `getCalculator2Port` in the class `Calculator2Service`. If you're sure you've done this, please check the spells and note that Java is a case sensitive language.

BTW you may want to access `getCalculator2Port` while it's not visible in this scope, e.g. it's a `private` method, however in this case you get notified as "The method ... from the type ... is not visible".

Answer (score 0):

Calculator2Port is a factory method which returns a Calculator2 object here. You should define an interface or abstract class like

```
public interface Calculator2 {

    public double add(double a, double b);
    public double sub(double a, double b);
}
```

then in Calculator2Service should have a method like

```
Calculator2 getCalculator2Port(){
    Calculator2 c = new Calculator2(){
       public double add(double a,double b){
          return(a+b);
       }

       public double sub (double a, double b){
          return(a-b);
       }
    }
    return(c);
 }
```